# Hide window with Process using username and password

Tags: c#, winforms, process

I'm trying to get the result of command with wmic.exe on my C# windows form application. I achieved it in my code, but I wants to hide the window that opens for a half of second and then closed, when I call to my function.
This is the code:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "wmic.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "A COMMAND";
p.StartInfo.UserName = "";
SecureString secure = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in "")
{
    secure.AppendChar(c);
}
p.StartInfo.Password = secure;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
return output;
```

Comment: the problem can be you called wmic.. you cant determine what it then potentially does. So like any console app you and i  can throw up a windows form, the createnowindow hides what would have been the console but cant block that form

Comment: Well, I tried run this command in cmd also and it is the same result. do you have an idea how I can somehow block it? Without using username and password attriubies the window is never showing, but I have to use it.

Comment: If you include /user and /password does this not stop it?

Comment: what do you mean? I meant if I'm opening the wmic.exe without a username and password attributes it does not opening the window.

Comment: Im talking your arguments get "/username me /password allsecrets restofparameters"

Comment: @BugFinder Sorry I didn't understand what you means. Can you explain?

Comment: Im not sure how much more clear I can make that. You have arguments of "A COMMAND" .. ok have you tried making that "/username whateverusername /password whatevertheirpasswordis A COMMAND"

Comment: Don't use the Process class to do this, favor the System.Management namespace.  You'll like the [WMI Code Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) utility.  It lets you experiment and generates the C# code you need.  Copy/paste the code you need to set the username+password from [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.connectionoptions.username(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you. Can you give me an example on how I can start a cmd or wmic, pass with arguments and usernamd and password with this method?

Comment: You don't need an "example" when the WMI Code Creator tool generates the code you need.  Five minutes is of course not enough to try it.  Try it.

Comment: @HansPassant  Thanks. I'll look on it.